# How to describe a generic input to a smart contract in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am developing a POC with Hyperledger Composer. I have one asset that needs to be generic. I explain; in finance there are different types of contracts like forward, options, and many other types of flexible contracts. I need to model it in my code. So I decided to consider contract as an asset. When the asset is called how the underlying commodities of that asset would be traded depends on the type of contract they are called from. In other words the input of the smart contract is generic and the behavior depends on the type of contract (remember, contract is an asset, I don't mean smart contract here).

In order to reach this, I need to have polymorphism so that the pulled contract (an asset) itself determines how trade should be done. I would like to know if it is possible to have generic inputs in a smart cotnract? Do we have polymorphism in Hyperledger Fabric? If the answer is yes, I appreciate if you guide me how I can do it? And if it doesn't support polymorphism, then how is it possible to implement this? Is there any architecture that you suggest to overcome this limitation?

I appreciate any help.

Thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: From a H/L Composer perpective you would model your generic Contract asset as you've described it in your model file.  Note that the whole model you define in H/L Composer IS also part, of the runtime smart contract (as well as the transaction logic, ACL rules, queries etc etc) or business network, just FYI. Your inputs to the smart contract is/are the transactions that invoke it (eg say PullContract) and 'how' the contract is 'pulled' depends on the inputs.

Comment: Are you calling the 'smart contract' (via a transaction) from a client application with the 'type of contract they are called from' provided to the transaction? That would be the easiest way - then your transaction logic can deterministically execute 'how the underlying commodities of that asset would be traded'. Does this help?

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony Hi, yes that is what I am thinking of. To send the type of contract as an input to the smart contract. So if it is an option, or a future or anything else together with the other arguments.  Do you think it is a suitable way to invoke the smart contract?

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony Also have I understood correctly that we are using typescript to write smart contracts. Since typescript is supporting polymorphism, I can override trade method in logic.js. Is that right?

Comment: the smart contract logic is packaged up as part of the business network that gets installed on the remote peers ((native NodeJS chaincode) - in 'however many organisations are in your blockchain network' - and the transaction logic part of that smart contract is based on javascript

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony your first comment is a suitable answer together with typescript supporting polymorphism. Would you please provide it in the answer section? i cannot tick your comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a Hyperledger Composer perpective,  you would model your generic Contract asset as you've described it in your model file.

Note that the whole model you define in H/L Composer IS also part, of the executable smart contract (as well as the transaction logic, ACL rules, queries etc etc) or business network, just FYI. Your inputs to the smart contract is/are the transactions that invoke it (eg say PullContract) and 'how' the contract is 'pulled' depends on the inputs.

The smart contract transaction logic (javascript) is packaged up as part of the business network that gets installed on the remote peers (native NodeJS chaincode) - in however many organisations are in your blockchain network.